# If statement in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will wither show all or just current items based on the "deletedbyuser" column.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_FWPF]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @userLabs varchar(max),
    @showall char(1) = 'N'
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;

select dat.* from brFWPFileR br
full outer join  datFWPFileS  dat
on br.FileS_ID=dat.FileS_ID
where (br.Lab_ID in =@userLabs or dat.UploadedByLab_ID=@userLabs)
and
if @showall = 'N' 
dat.DeletedyByUserID is NULL
else
dat.DeletedyByUserID = dat.DeletedyByUserID
end if



END
```

however i'm getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'."

i tried the same with a `case when` statement, but it's still not working.

Comment: If is only for control flow, it is NEVER allowed in a Select/insert/update or delete.  You use OR  or CASE in SQL statements, you use IF to determine which SQL statement to run.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you are looking for

```
select dat.* from brFWPFileR br
full outer join  datFWPFileS  dat
on br.FileS_ID=dat.FileS_ID
where (br.Lab_ID in =@userLabs or dat.UploadedByLab_ID=@userLabs)
and
(
(@showall = 'N' AND dat.DeletedyByUserID is NULL)
OR
(@showall = 'Y' AND dat.DeletedyByUserID = dat.DeletedyByUserID)
)
```

The actual criteria after the @Showall="X" may vary depending on the results you are looking for under each criteria for the @Showall variable.